# Disable/Deactivate/Eliminate Oldest Records from SQL Table while retrieval data by queries

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL tables in database where thousands of records are inserting on daily basis. This leads to slow of query responses in huge database records. As we have to get data of current month or current year for different types of reporting.

So is there any method where oldest records can be deactivate/eliminate/disable old records, so that they should not be include during retrieval of data.

By this our queries response can be more faster. The oldest records should remain in the table for historical reporting, by giving any special permissions.

Comment: Do you have date based indexes in your table, with the other columns needed for the reports?

Comment: I have created indexes on some columns of tables but we have to retrieve data for different types of reporting  by applying constraints on different columns. So we cannot index every column of table. Second. the indexes makes insertion slow in table because it has to update indexes upon each record insertion and i have high volume of data insertion load.

Comment: I assume "some columns" means "no, we don't have anything date related". Well, that's where you should start.

Comment: if index means by auto incremented column, yes i have these columns in database. but my question is that is there any way where i can eliminate/deactivate old records that they should not be take part in data retrieval

Comment: No, index does not mean auto incremented column. It means an index on the table, on the column that you decide what is "older"

Comment: Have you looked at table [partitioning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

I see possible 3 ways to solve your problem. 
The easiest is to use `Filtered Indexes`. It might not be a case for your queries, but worth to try and I'd start looking at this option first.

Second way is to create tables for `OLD` records and move old data there on daily basis. In order to retrieve ALL data, if needed, you have to create special procedures or unionized views.

The third way is most expensive. You can install SQL Server 2016 and use `Azure` for stretching your database into the cloud. Old records will be transparently moved to `Azure` and there is no any programming effort needed. However, as I mentioned, it will be expensive.